# Trying to pass spaces when launching Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, process.start

I'm trying to launch an external instance of Chrome from a c# Windows form. It works fine as long as there are no spaces in the path of the local html file. If there are though Chrome stops at the first space.
e.g. : "file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual"
I tried to fix this by replacing spaces in the string with "%20" like Chrome usually does. Now I get this garbled address:
"file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual%2520Studio%2520%2012/TEMP.html"

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
string chromeTempFilePath = tempFilePath.Replace(" ", "%20");

Process.Start(browserPaths[2], chromeTempFilePath);//launch Chrome
```

`Process.Start` works fine for both Firefox and IE 9 with the spaces in the path.
Any help would be much appreciated as I'm more or less stumped!

Comment: %2520% indicates double spaces

Comment: Why is Chrome adding a space then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `string.Replace` method and change your `Process.Start` to look like this:

```
Process.Start(browserPaths[2], string.Format("\"{0}\"", chromeTempFilePath));
```

You just need to wrap it all in double quotes. This worked for me with Chrome, but I didn't check other browsers.

Comment: That works thanks! I should really have thought of it myself, odd that it works for firefox and IE but not Chrome though. (I'll select this as an answer in 3 minutes :) )

Comment: Note: a recent change in Chrome introduced a [bug](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/76204149?hl=en) whereby opening local file with spaces in the path would open multiple bogus tabs, one for each space-delimited piece. This would happen even if you wrapped the whole path in quotes. This has been fixed (at least as of 86.0.4240.75).

Comment: it is just like path does not work if it has spaces but works when it is wrapped in double quotes when we are using cmd or powershell . cd "some path with spaces"