# Files with space in path not opening correctly

Tags: google-chrome

This is strange to me, I can't open the HTML file which has space char in his path!

For instance: I want to open `C:\Users\my code`

It opens `C:\Users\my` in one window

and opens `code` in another window!

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your Chrome (by closing it and then reopening or through the settings page) or otherwise just drag your files next to other tabs to open them.

Answer (score 0):

The filename needs to be enclosed in double quotes, i.e.

```
"C:\Users\my code"
```

Duplicate of [Trying to pass spaces when launching Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533301/trying-to-pass-spaces-when-launching-chrome)